# Convert E, d M y HH:mm:ss x string date format to yyyy-mm-dd with databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

everything is in the title. I tried this without success so far:

```
date_format(to_date(col("data")["createdAt"], 'E, d M y HH:mm:ss x'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

all values returned are `null`

This is an example of input `Fri, 12 Jun 20 07:49:17 +0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_date` does not accept weekdays (`E`), so you need to remove that using `split` first. Also you need to fix the formats (note capitalization):

```
date_format(to_date(split(col("data")["createdAt"], ', ')[1], 'd MMM yy HH:mm:ss Z'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```